# I can't parse a Jquery ajax JSON response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing, response

I am trying to parse the JSON results from an AJAX call, but do to the limitations of the server I am only able to get one large string.  There are several elements returned, but the data I need to consume is all thrown into a single element.  Now here is the tricky thing... if I use firebug the response has a JSON tag and everything looks like a proper JSON object, but when I try to map or view the results using an alert I notice they are single quotes instead of double quotes.  i've tried replacing the quotes to no avail as well.  I'm pretty much stumped at this point.

```
the alert would print out something simular to this: [{'id':'2663','parent':'2663'},{'id':'2664','parent':'2664'},]

        $.ajax({
            url: myURL,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(docData) {
                var docResults = docData.responseText;
                alert(docResults);
                $(docResults).each(function(i,val){
                    $.each(val,function(k,v){
                          console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
                    });
                });                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your server is returning invalid JSON.

Comment: Well don't post client side script, post you server script that returns the responce instead...

Comment: There is an _evil_ solution.

Comment: Make your json valid and your problem will go away. Most server-side languages now come with a json encode method that will encode your server-side array or struct into a valid json string.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of this... unfortunately I can't change the server side code.  The application is an IBM enterprise application.  Everything about it doesn't make sense.  Also as an fyi- I have tried making my callback on 'success' but that won't trigger the callback again because of how the response is being sent back.  DANG YOU IBM!!  I guess I'll keep trying to figure out a hack to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to fix this is to fix it on the server, however, there is a way to fix it client-side using the dataFilter callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: myURL,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "json",
  dataFilter: function(response) {

    // *** Note: this will have to be modified if quotes 
    // *** can be contained within the data. It doesn't appear as though
    // *** that is the case with the data you have provided. 

    return response
      // fix trailing comma
      .replace("},]","}]")
      // fix quotes
      .replace(/'/g,'"'));
  },
  success: function (response) {
    $.each(response,function(){
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
});
```